# Does the contrastive は always rise in pitch?

Tags: nuances, particle-は, pitch-accent, intonation

At [3:03](https://youtu.be/bRSOBvEKI8E?t=183) the speaker says

> この人は

- I could be wrong, but it sounds like she's saying this as "koNOHITOWA" rather than "koNOHITOwa".
- According to my bilingual dictionary, Heiban is not an acceptable pitch accent for この人. Instead it should be either "koNOHITOwa" or "koNOhitowa".

**Question:** Assuming I'm right above, can Odaka words sometimes become Heiban when the contrastive は is used? E.g. if the speaker wants to say "as for *this* person (as opposed to these others)...", will the は necessarily rise in pitch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

She says このひとは{LHLLH}.

この＼ひと is the standard accent for that word/phrase, so there is nothing unusual there.

As for the raised は, you can raise any particle to make it sound emphasized, though I would consider this to be in the realm of intonation as opposed to pitch accent (because it is not lexical).

Such an intonation pattern is not required for a は to be the contrastive は, but it does often cooccur with it.

Comment: Thanks for the correction :S I listened to it about 100 more times on repeat, and still can't hear it as このひとは{LHLLH}. Instead I keep hearing このひとは{LHHHH}, which is super demoralizing since this is supposed to be a video for children.

When you hear pitch accent (in this word or in others), are you focused more on the pitch *raises*, the pitch *drops*, or something else? I think what my brain has learned to do is focus only on exaggerated pitch raises right before drops; these might only occur in dictionary settings though and not as much in real life.

Comment: It would be immensely useful if there were a Chrome plugin which could show live pitch graphs on YouTube videos.

Comment: @George - Try **saying** このひ, このひと, このひとは by adding one mora at a time but keeping the pitch high. The final result will sound different from what you heard on the video.